# Maintaining Position of Array During Navigation

Tags: javascript, arrays, navigation

I have an array of images that are utilized to replace the DIV background on click.  I have two buttons (basically forward and reverse)and what I am trying to accomplish is that for the forward (or back) buttons to maintain last position of the array prior to executing the function, here is the code;

```
var ImagesB = []; 
ImagesB[0]="images/image1.png";
ImagesB[1]="images/image2.png";
ImagesB[2]="images/image3.png";

var i = 1;

function updateImgB(){
  var url = 'url(' + ImagesB[i] + ')';
    document.getElementById('DIV1').style.backgroundImage = url;
    i = (i + 1)%(ImagesB.length);
}

function reverseImgB(){
  var url = 'url(' + ImagesB[i] + ')';
    document.getElementById('DIV1).style.backgroundImage = url;
    i = (i - 1)%(ImagesB.length);
    if(i < 0){i = ImagesB.length - 1};
}
```

Currently this works, however say for instance you execute `updateImgB`, it ends with the next number in the array, eg: `i + 1`, therefore if I execute the `reverseImgB` function, it begins on the next image ie: `2`, then will work backwards.  It is my intention for it to work backwards from the current image, and vice versa.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subtract `1` from `i` before changing the Image:

```
function reverseImgB(){
    i = (i - 1)%(ImagesB.length);
    if(i < 0){i = ImagesB.length - 1};
    var url = 'url(' + ImagesB[i] + ')';
    document.getElementById('DIV1).style.backgroundImage = url;
}
```

Comment: Luca, thank you.  This does work!  One issue is that if you navigate forward one image, then attempt to go back it takes two clicks to get to the previous image and vice versa.

Comment: And that is still an issue?

Comment: Not necessarily, if this is the only way to do it with this code that will work.  Is there a way for the code to know what image the array is currently on to avoid have to go back (or forward) to the current image prior to advancing?